# How can you prevent serialization of DependencyObjectType info on DependencyObjects using Newtonsoft JSON?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, serialization

When serializing `DependencyObject` derivative classes using *Newtonsoft's JSON* (version 8.0.0) for *.Net / C#* I notice that it always serializes the `DependencyObjectType` and `Dispatcher` objects along with all of my derivative class' properties. Since the `DependencyObjectType` and `Dispatcher` objects come from the `DependencyObject` class I'm inheriting from, how can I add smart tags or attributes (such as `[JsonIgnore]`) to prevent them from being serialized? Or am I perhaps thinking about it the wrong way?

Example class code:

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

Serializer code:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(jw, MyInstance);
}
```

When serialized I get this massive blob (all but the top line are unwanted):

```
{
    "MyProperty": 0,
    "DependencyObjectType": {
      "Id": 148,
      "SystemType": "MyProject.MyClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "BaseType": {
        "Id": 0,
        "SystemType": "System.Windows.DependencyObject, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx",
        "BaseType": null,
        "Name": "DependencyObject"
      },
      "Name": "MyClass"
    },
    "IsSealed": false,
    "Dispatcher": {
      "Thread": {
        "ManagedThreadId": 17,
        "ExecutionContext": null,
        "Priority": 2,
        "IsAlive": true,
        "IsThreadPoolThread": true,
        "IsBackground": true,
        "ThreadState": 4,
        "ApartmentState": 1,
        "CurrentUICulture": "en-US",
        "CurrentCulture": "en-US",
        "Name": null
      },
      "HasShutdownStarted": false,
      "HasShutdownFinished": false,
      "Hooks": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[OptIn](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm)** approach to suppress serialization of all properties in the type hierarchy except required properties:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
```

And mark properties for serialization with:

```
[JsonProperty]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could mark your types with [`MemberSerialization.OptIn`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm) and [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) as is explained in [@Filip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326836/how-can-you-prevent-serialization-of-dependencyobjecttype-info-on-dependencyobje/35326938#35326938).

A second answer is to use a [custom `ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) that omits all properties of a specified base class, or a collection of base classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contract resolver to ignore properties of a single given type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver<T> : IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    static IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver<T> instance;

    static IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver() { instance = new IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver<T>(); }

    public static IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver<T> Instance { get { return instance; } }

    IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver() : base(new[] { typeof(T) }) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contract resolver to ignore properties of any number of given types.
/// </summary>
public class IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly HashSet<Type> toIgnore;
    readonly HashSet<Type> toIgnoreAndBase;

    public IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver(IEnumerable<Type> toIgnore)
    {
        if (toIgnore == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.toIgnore = new HashSet<Type>(toIgnore);
        this.toIgnoreAndBase = new HashSet<Type>(toIgnore.SelectMany(t => t.BaseTypesAndSelf()));
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        if (type.BaseTypesAndSelf().Any(t => toIgnore.Contains(t)))
        {
            var filtered = list.Where(p => !toIgnoreAndBase.Contains(p.DeclaringType)).ToList();
            return filtered;
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

With a custom contract resolver, it is not necessary to add attributes to each type.

Then serialize as follows:

```
var settings =  new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = IgnoreTypePropertiesContractResolver<DependencyObject>.Instance };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass { MyProperty = 101 }, settings);
```